# Running python script from Azure SSIS

Tags: python, azure, ssis

I have a set of python scripts that are run from SSIS execute process as part of a larger SSIS project.  I am trying to run the SSIS code on an Azure Data Factory.  I can get everything to run except the python scripts.  I have put the python scripts in Azure files and mounted them and reference them from the SSIS exec process.  What I don't understand is how do I reference the pythonw.exe?  How do I install the python interpreter with the proper libraries inside Azure?

I have searched for many hours for an answer to this.  I see there are a lot of questions about running Python scripts in SSIS, which I already do.  I am reasonably sure that I can run python scripts from a Data Factory without using SSIS.  But I can't find how to run python scripts in SSIS in an Azure Data Frame.  It seems to me that this should be able to be done.  Can someone either tell me what I am missing or if it can't be done, I need to know that too so that I can come up with a different solution.